# I want to pick a color from a large set of colors

Tags: java, swing

Here i created a program. My main method create many shapes (boxes, triangles ...) I want to

have a button that if i click on it I can pick a color from large set of colors?

This is the main program ( with only the boxes):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Kaleidescope extends JFrame implements MouseListener, ActionListener, MouseMotionListener {

    Box b;
    Box[] boxes; // 2-d array of Box objects, form a color pallet
    int boxCount;
    JButton boxButton;

    int x1, y1; // mousePressed
    int w1, z1; // mouseEntered

    int mode = 1; // 1 = line, 2= boxes, 3 = oval, 4= text, 5 = SG, twoLines = 7. 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hi there.");
        new Kaleidescope();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        boxes = new Box[20];
        boxCount = 0;

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        boxButton = new JButton("Boxes");
        add(boxButton);

        boxButton.addActionListener(this);
        setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        setVisible(true);

    }

    // returns a random color

    public Color randomColor() {
        int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);

        return new Color(red, green, blue);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        System.out.println("click at x=" + e.getX() + " y=" + e.getY());

        // convert window coords to box array indexes.

        // These were adjusted slightly after the video was made

        // (no more flakiness, these are right on target).

        int boxi = (e.getX() - 10) / 20; // convert mouse x to box index
        int boxj = (e.getY() - 40) / 20;

        System.out.println("click at boxi=" + boxi + " boxj=" + boxj);

        // set extra box to the color that we clicked on

        if (mode == 2) {
            boxes[boxCount++] = new Box(e.getX(), e.getY(), randomColor());
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == boxButton) {
            mode = 2;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < boxCount; i++) {
            boxes[i].drawMe(g);
        }
    }

}
```

This Is the other class for the box (connected to the main program to draw my box)

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Box {
    protected Color color;
    protected int x, y; // pixels from upper left to upper left corner

    // make a box
    public Box(int x1, int y1, Color c1) {
        x = x1;
        y = y1;
        color = c1;
    }

    public void drawMe(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    }

    public void setColor(Color c) {
        color = c;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

Here is another class

```
package kaleidescope;

public class Point {

    int x;
    int y;

    public Point( int x1, int y1 )    {
        x = x1; y = y1;
    }

}
```

Also this class

```
package kaleidescope;

import java.awt.*;

public abstract class Shape {
    protected Color color;
    abstract public void drawMe( Graphics g );
}
```

Comment: "I want to have a button that if i click on it I can pick a color from large set of colors?" Does the question mark indicate that you are uncertain of what you want? :)

Comment: Please provide compileable code!

Comment: Ok not sure how to make it clear. But I want to pick a color from a large set of colors

Comment: Which bits of the above code are actually relevant to your problem?  And what have you tried, in order to do what you want?

Comment: So you're looking for a way to make a colorpicker? Google is a great place to start. If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're looking for whats called `ColorPicker`

Answer (score 0):

What about the [Java Color Chooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html)